# Recursively remove line-endings from string values in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I have a hash object that could be arbitrarily large - keys are always strings, but values could be strings, arrays, or other hashes. I want to recursively walk through the object and if the value of any particular key (or the value of any array) is a string, I want to strip line endings and leading and trailing whitespace (\r\n, \t, etc")

Do I need to write this algorithm myself or is there some faster ruby-esque way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write it yourself.  One way to do it is:

```
def strip_hash_values!(hash)
  hash.each do |k, v|
    case v
    when String
      v.strip!
    when Array
      v.each {|av| av.strip!}
    when Hash
      strip_hash_values!(v)
     end
  end
end
```

This method modifies the original hash:

```
hash = {:a => [" a ", " b ", " c "], :b => {:x => "xyz   "}, :c => "abc    "}

strip_hash_values!(hash)

puts hash
# returns {:b=>{:x=>"xyz"}, :c=>"abc", :a=>["a", "b", "c"]}
```

Comment: What if `v` is an array containing one or more arrays or hashes?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it.

**Code**

```
def strip_strings(o)
  case o
  when Hash
    o.each do |k,v|
      o[k] = case v
             when String
               v.strip
             else  
               strip_strings(v)
             end
    end
  else # Array
    o.map do |e|
      case e
      when String
        e.strip
      else  
        strip_strings(e)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
h = { a: [b: { c: " cat ", d: [" dog ", {e: " pig " }] }], f: " pig " }
  #=> {:a=>[{:b=>{:c=>" cat ", :d=>[" dog ", {:e=>" pig "}]}}], :f=>" pig "}

strip_strings(h)
  #=> {:a=>[{:b=>{:c=>"cat", :d=>["dog", {:e=>"pig"}]}}], :f=>"pig"}
```